# ListView with two edit text on each row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

How to store and retrieve editText from a listview that have 2 editText on each row?

With this code, when I write something to one editText, it copy the value to all others.

```
public class CheckoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<JsonObject> mObjs;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private SessionManager session;
    private float Value = 0;
    private int tax = 0;
    private float Total = 0;
    private int viewID = 0;
    private EnhancedListView listview;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    static DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayFirstName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrayLastName = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CheckoutAdapter(Context context, List<JsonObject> objs, EnhancedListView mListView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mObjs = objs;
        this.listview = mListView;

        for (int i = 0; i < mObjs.size(); i++) {
            arrayFirstName.add("");
            arrayLastName.add("");
        }
    }
    //Classe ViewHolder
    public final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView ticketValue;
        public TextView ticketItem;
        public TextView ticketOpcao;
        public TextView ticketTax;
        public TextView ticketTitle;
        public TextView ticketDate;
        public TextView ticketFullName;
        public EditText ticketFirstName;
        public EditText ticketLastName;
        public ImageView ticketImageThumb;
        int position;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mObjs.remove(position);

    }

    public void insert(int position, JsonObject item) {
        mObjs.add(position, item);

    }

    @Override
    //Contar a quntidade de linhas.
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mObjs.size();
    }

    @Override
    //Pegar o item conforme a posição.
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mObjs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    //ID do item (refere-se a posição em que ele se encontra).
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View vi=convertView;
         //Se não houver nenhuma View, uma nova view é criada.
            if(convertView==null) 
            {
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_checkout, null);
                Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Oswald-Bold.otf");
                final View origView = vi;
                vi.findViewById(R.id.action_delete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       listview.delete(((ViewHolder)origView.getTag()).position);
                    }
                });
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ticketItem = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
            holder.ticketOpcao = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvOpcao);
            holder.ticketTax = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTaxa);
            holder.ticketValue = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
                holder.ticketValue.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ticketTitle = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                holder.ticketTitle.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ticketDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
                holder.ticketDate.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ticketFullName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
                holder.ticketFullName.setTypeface(font);
            holder.ticketFirstName = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
            holder.ticketLastName = (EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
            holder.ticketImageThumb = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgFlyerSub);
                holder.position = position;
                holder.ticketFirstName.addTextChangedListener(FirstNameChangedListener(position));
                holder.ticketLastName.addTextChangedListener(LastNameChangedListener(position));
                holder.ticketFirstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(FirstNameFocusChangeListener(position));
                holder.ticketLastName.setOnFocusChangeListener(LastNameFocusChangeListener(position));

            vi.setTag(holder);
            //Caso já exista uma view o objeto holder recebe o getTag da View vi.
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
            holder.ticketItem.setText(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.JSON.JSON_ITEM).getAsString());
            holder.ticketOpcao.setText(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.JSON.JSON_OPCAO).getAsString());
            holder.ticketTax.setText("Taxa de serviço:" + mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.JSON.JSON_TAX).getAsString() + "%");
            holder.ticketValue.setText("R$" + String.valueOf(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.JSON.JSON_VALUE).getAsInt()) + ",00");
            holder.ticketDate.setText(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.KEY.KEY_EVENTDATE).getAsString());
            holder.ticketTitle.setText(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get(Constants.JSON.JSON_EVENTTITLE).getAsString());


            holder.ticketFirstName.setText(arrayFirstName.get(holder.position));
            holder.ticketLastName.setText(arrayLastName.get(holder.position));


        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ico_load_imagem)
                .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5))
                .build();
        imageLoader.displayImage(mObjs.get(position).getAsJsonObject().get("thumbPrincipal").getAsString(), holder.ticketImageThumb, options);




        return vi;
    }

    private View.OnFocusChangeListener LastNameFocusChangeListener(final int position) {
        return new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    viewID = holder.position;


                }
            }
        };
    }

    private View.OnFocusChangeListener FirstNameFocusChangeListener(final int position) {
        return new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){

                    viewID = holder.position;


                }
            }
        };
    }

    private TextWatcher FirstNameChangedListener(final int position) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String itemName = s.toString();
                arrayFirstName.add(viewID, itemName);
            }
        };
    }

    private TextWatcher LastNameChangedListener(final int position) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String itemName = s.toString();
                arrayLastName.add(viewID, itemName);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Removed setId and JSON.

Comment: could be that you are setting same id `setId(position)` for both`ticketFirstName` and `ticketLastName`

Comment: Your comment should be en English. About your question, the comportment you have is about View ids.

Comment: Hey, what you do is really bad, please try to separate the json stuff with the adapter. An adapter for a listview is just an adapter, it only displays data.

Comment: @Yazan, I dont even use setId atm... it was just an atempt to put it to work..

Comment: @Paul, Ok thx, I can do it, but it dont solve my main answer.

Comment: Is hard to understand if there is the problem in your code, when you have such messy code, with commented code, I suggest making a clear adapter, and editing the answer.

Comment: @Paul, I just did it, I just put my code as example about what I have tried, but the problem is about have two edittext in the same row in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Your holder is a member of your class, it's wrong.
Remove it from this place. Every line of your listview has its own holder.
This holder is "sticked" to the view by the setTag method.

In listeners that used holder, you have to get the holder from the view that send the event.
For this, the following code should work:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener FirstNameFocusChangeListener(final int position) {
    return new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder ) v.getTag();
                viewID = holder.position;
            }
        }
    };
}
```